# Understanding the computation of p-value and its v-test by catdes() of FactoMineR

Tags: r, distributions, p-value, chi-squared-test, quantiles

One of the functions that helps to characterize clusters is the catdesc() function. The output of this function is very informative giving the following bits of information:
`Cla/Mod`, `Mod/Cla`, `Glabal`, `p-value`, and `v-test`. In this post, I want to know what is going on under the hood regarding the calculation of `v-test` and its p-value using the catdes() fucntion:

**FactoMineR::catdes() function code snippet**

```
FactoMineR::catdes
...
aux5 <- (1 - 2 * as.integer(aux2 > aux3)) * 
                      qnorm(aux4/2)
...
```

This is about calculating the p-value and its v-test when describing clusters by categories of a categorical variable. As far as I understood, since we have two categorical variables (categories and clusters) we perform the Chi-square test directly first then we get the quantile of the resulting p-value in a normal distribution as stated below in the book, in case we have more than two categories (asymmetrical) then we convert `n x n` contingency table to `2 x 2` one as explained on p157 of "Exploratory Multivariate Analysis by Example Using R" 2nd edition by François Husson, we read the following:

> The v-test here corresponds to the quantile of the normal distribution
> which is associated with p-value; the sign indicates an over- or
> underrepresentation (Lebart et al.,2006).

I found this [discussion](https://groups.google.com/g/factominer-users/c/55w8gvADWJo) affirming the above account by the author of the package and the book explaining the output of this function but the manual calculation of the p-value remains unclear and I couldn't replicate the same output as in the following MWE.

**Book excerpts**

[image]

this is when we have more than two categories or clusters:

[image]

now we look at the output of the `catdes()` function:

[image]

As you can see the `v-test` was `6.64` for the **luxury** cluster of *type* (has 6 clusters) and the cetegory **specialist** shop of the *place of purchase* variable (has 3 categories).

**Calculating the v-test from the p-value**

If we take the p-value of the **specialist.shop** we have to get the `qnorm()` thereof and divide it by two according to a helpful comment by @AllanCameron and this is also supported by code snippet of the function:

```
qnorm(3.16e-11 / 2, mean = 0, sd = 1, lower.tail = FALSE)
## 6.639
```

This is essentially the same figure shown in the table `6.64`. But the question why do we take the qnorm() quantile of a normal distribution function when we originally using a Chi-square test for a contingency table?

Unfortunately the `tea` dataset in the book is not the same one in the current package version of FactoMineR. I couldn't reproduce the example in the book for this reason.

So let's have a look at the current tea dataset in the package to see if we can reproduce the v-test using the qnorm() function as above.

The following example was also mentioned in the [website](http://factominer.free.fr/factomethods/categories-description.html) of FactoMineR package.

**MWE: tea dataset and how to calculate p-value and its v-test**

```
library(FactoMineR)
data(tea)
res <- catdes(tea, num.var=23, proba=0.05)
#tea: the data set used
#num.var: the index of the variable to characterize
#proba: the significance threshold considered to characterize the category (by default 0.05)
```

**Output of catdes()**

```
   > res$category$`+60`
                           Cla/Mod Mod/Cla Global   p.value v.test
SPC=non-worker              56.250  94.737  21.33 1.407e-26 10.670
work=Not.work               17.840 100.000  71.00 7.674e-07  4.943
Tea=black                   24.324  47.368  24.67 1.190e-03  3.241
Sport=Not.sportsman         19.835  63.158  40.33 2.726e-03  2.997
where=chain store+tea shop  21.795  44.737  26.00 7.778e-03  2.662
slimming=slimming           24.444  28.947  15.00 1.822e-02  2.361
How=other                   44.444  10.526   3.00 1.958e-02  2.334
always=Not.always           15.736  81.579  65.67 2.452e-02  2.249
price=p_upscale             22.642  31.579  17.67 2.532e-02  2.236
SPC=middle                   2.500   2.632  13.33 2.579e-02 -2.229
always=always                6.796  18.421  34.33 2.452e-02 -2.249
How=alone                    9.231  47.368  65.00 1.833e-02 -2.359
slimming=No.slimming        10.588  71.053  85.00 1.822e-02 -2.361
where=chain store            8.333  42.105  64.00 3.632e-03 -2.908
Sport=sportsman              7.821  36.842  59.67 2.726e-03 -2.997
SPC=employee                 0.000   0.000  19.67 1.291e-04 -3.828
Tea=Earl Grey                6.736  34.211  64.33 6.364e-05 -3.999
SPC=student                  0.000   0.000  23.33 1.870e-05 -4.280
work=work                    0.000   0.000  29.00 7.674e-07 -4.943
```

Let's look at the age group `60+` and the category of **non-worker** of the *Socio-Professional Category (SPC)* variable. We see the v-test equals 10.670, however when I do the `qnorm()` of the p-value 1.4e-26,

```
qnorm(res$category$`+60`[1, 4] / 2, mean = 0, sd = 1, lower.tail = FALSE) # 10.67
```

So again I get the same figure as in the catdes() which affirms the fact that v-test is computed by taking the quantile of the normal distribution function divided by 2.

**My trial to compute the p-value**

Now I want to compute the p-value using the tea dataset. According to the book excerpts I provided above, when we have a variable and/or cluster with more than 2 categories we have to convert that into a 2 x 2 contingency table and do chi-square test as shown in book table 3.7:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tea %>%
    mutate(age60 = ifelse(age_Q == "+60", "+60", "other")) %>%
    mutate(spcNW = ifelse(SPC == "non-worker", "non-worker", "misc")) %>%
    mutate(age60 = as.factor(age60)) %>%
    mutate(spcNW = as.factor(spcNW)) %>%
    select(age_Q, SPC, age60, spcNW)
```

then I performed Chi-square test on the data as follows:

```
gmodels::CrossTable(df$age60, df$spcNW , fisher = FALSE, chisq = TRUE, expected = TRUE, prop.c = FALSE, prop.t = FALSE, prop.chisq = FALSE, sresid = TRUE, format = "SPSS")
```

**Output of the Chi-square test**

```
   Cell Contents
|-------------------------|
|                   Count |
|         Expected Values |
|             Row Percent |
|            Std Residual |
|-------------------------|

Total Observations in Table:  300 

             | df$spcNW 
    df$age60 |       misc  | non-worker  |  Row Total | 
-------------|------------|------------|------------|
         +60 |         2  |        36  |        38  | 
             |    29.893  |     8.107  |            | 
             |     5.263% |    94.737% |    12.667% | 
             |    -5.102  |     9.797  |            | 
-------------|------------|------------|------------|
       other |       234  |        28  |       262  | 
             |   206.107  |    55.893  |            | 
             |    89.313% |    10.687% |    87.333% | 
             |     1.943  |    -3.731  |            | 
-------------|------------|------------|------------|
Column Total |       236  |        64  |       300  | 
-------------|------------|------------|------------|

 
Statistics for All Table Factors


Pearson's Chi-squared test 
------------------------------------------------------------
Chi^2 =  139.7     d.f. =  1     p =  3.1e-32 

Pearson's Chi-squared test with Yates' continuity correction 
------------------------------------------------------------
Chi^2 =  134.7     d.f. =  1     p =  3.775e-31 

 
       Minimum expected frequency: 8.107
```

As you can see the p-value here is 3.1e-32 but catdes() had a different p-value 1.407e-26, why?

**Variables related to the MWE**

$I_{qt} = 36$

$I_q = 38$

$I_t = 64$

$I = 300$

$\frac{I_{qt}}{I} = \frac{I_t}{I} = \frac{36}{38} = \frac{64}{300}$

What did the book below table 3.7 mean when it says the two proportions are equal nuder the null hypothesis of independence, is this not the Chi-square $X^{2}$ test?

**Questions**

1. If we are to perform Chi-square test on categorical data, why should we take the quantile of the p-value from a normal distribution and not from the Chi-square distribution, I mean why do we use `qnorm()` rather than `qchisq()`  to compute the v-test? What is the statistical reason behind choosing qnorm() rather than qchisq()?
2. To know what is going on under the hood, how did we get the p-value for the non-worker SPC with the 60+ category (1.4e-26)?

**Software versions**

R version 4.2.2 Patched (2022-11-10 r83330)

FactoMineR_2.6

Comment: You should have flagged the original post for migration so that the comments would appear here.

Comment: Flag it.  When it arrives here, we can delete this one as a duplicate.

Comment: @whuber flagged in need of moderator intervention. Thanks.

Comment: @whuber I edited the post to be more precise on the p-value and its v-test so it is no more the same original post. FYI. Thanks.